# Change server variable values that are logged in Elmah

Tags: c#, .net, webforms, elmah

I configured Elmah in my application and when I looked at the error logs I saw that  in the User section Elmah logged an ID instead of the current logged in username a shown below.

I was wondering if there is a place where I can change how the values of these server variables are set so I can put say an email or proper username in the Auth_User variable..Looking at Elmah documentation I was only able to figure out how to filter out Error logging but not actually how to update server variable values before logging.

[image: Elmah]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a blog post about exactly that: [Enrich ELMAH errors using error filtering hook](https://blog.elmah.io/enrich-elmah-errors-using-error-filtering-hook/).

To summarize, use ELMAH's error filtering to overwrite the message logged to ELMAH.

In `Global.asax.cs` add the following code:

```cs
void ErrorLog_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs args)
{
    var httpContext = args.Context as HttpContext;
    if (httpContext != null)
    {
        var error = new Error(args.Exception, httpContext);
        error.User = GetUserFromDatabase();
        ErrorLog.GetDefault(httpContext).Log(error);
        args.Dismiss();
    }
}
```

How you implement the line where you set the `User` property on `error` will be up to your application. But the code will let you set something like the user's name, username, or email.

Comment: Awesome..Thank you so much for your help :)